# Pass String array values to sql IN condition

Tags: java, servlets

I have String array like

```
String[] val=request.getParameterValues("Names");  
for(int i=0;i<val.length;i++){  
 //printval[i];
}
```

I would like to assign the values of String array to a sql statement as

How can I pass all the string values to sql condition? If array have the following values
`JAMES,SMITH, JAKE` etc, then I would pass it as

```
sql =  "where dept_name in('JAMES','SMITH','JAKE')";
```

Ideally I would want the string array values to be passed inside the in condition of sql.

Comment: Why can't you use a `StringBuilder` to build a pre-prepared statement?

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372046/getting-records-from-database-with-variable-condition/16372094#16372094) is what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a query as a filter and append this query to your main query.

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
String filter = "";

String[] val=request.getParameterValues("Names");  
for(int i=0;i<val.length;i++){  
 //printval[i];
 sb.append( "'"+val[i]+"'," );
}

filter = sb.ToString();
filter = filter.substring(0, filter.length()-1);

sql =  "where dept_name in("+filter+")";
```

Comment: I forgot to put the val as array, can you try it again?

Answer (score 3):

This is very simple!

just try:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;


StringUtils.join(new String[] {"Hello", "World", "!"}, ", ");
```

and you will have the string joined by commas

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
   StringBuilder csvStr = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<val.length;i++){
        if (val.length > 1 && i !=0) {
            csvStr.append(",");
        }
        csvStr.append ("'").append(val[i]).append("'");
    }
    System.out.println(csvStr);
```

Use csvStr.toString() into the sql you are using.

```
  sql =  "where dept_name in (".concat(csvStr.toString()).concat(")");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sql = "where dept_name in(select column_value from table(?))";
```

Then pass the Array to from JDBC.

```
Object[] dept = {"Dev","QA", "Support"};
Array deptArray = connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", dept);
preparedStatement.setArray(idx, deptArray);
```

Comment: How is *"select column_value from table(?)"* supposed to fit in here?

Comment: Issue with for loop and appending values in sql is security issue as it can cause sql injection issues.   If you still want to use, then you should use encode literals.

Comment: column_value will be pseudo column for the scalar nested table created by oracle.