# Build clause IN in Java to PL/SQL execution

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

I'm using the following Oracle PL/SQL procedure :

```
PROCEDURE PO_DEMO ( o_cur_task             OUT *****,
                    i_liste_name  IN     VARCHAR2)
IS 
  l_liste_name VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN      
  l_liste_name := i_liste_name;

OPEN o_cur_task FOR
   SELECT   ID
   FROM     TASK_TABLE
   WHERE    NAME IN (l_liste_name);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
     RAISE;

END PO_DEMO;
```

I call this in java with a service lawer with string param

```
String l_liste_name = "name1,name2";
```

This kind of variable search 'name1,name2' value not 'name1,','name2'
I tried adding ' char in my string var without success.

any Idea how to parse my java  string var ?

Regards.
Craftyman

Comment: What is the source of `l_liste_name`? is this a hard coded value or are you getting the values from some where else?

Comment: the java var l_list_name come from a parameter. I look for how to parse this value with ' for example to be correctly use in IN clause

Comment: What kind of parameter, is that a `request.getParameter()` or something else?

Comment: No it's in a java batch context

Comment: Try this approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/16461579/599528

Comment: Not working where i'm using "'name1','name2'" because IN clause is not build in java. It's a pl/sql procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Either the proc should separate comma separated values. Or you should pass it via a collection to the proc